# matching and appending(copying) every 3rd line without disturbing the 3rd line using perl

Tags: perl

I have a following lines in a file..

```
- VSSC!.extra196 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1055560 1571000 ) N ;
- VSSC!.extra197 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1055560 1571000 ) N ;
- VSSC!.extra198 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1043560 1571000 ) N ;
```

I want to append every 3rd line with first line..

eg: `- VSSC!.extra198 + NET VSSC!  + USE GROUND + SPECIAL

by using match operator I am able to catch the first line and 3rd line. and next task is, how to append and add a word called `+SPECIAL` to it?

```
use warnings;
my @array;

open(my $fh, "<", "sample.txt") or die "Failed to 

open file: $!\n";
while(<$fh>) {
     my $i; chomp; push @array, $_;
}

close $fh;

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{

     print "$array[i] $array[i+2] +SPECIAL \n";
}
```

Comment: Please try and fix the code markup. Both the input file and the code file should be indented with four spaces on each line. Leave the line before the start blank, and put four spaces on any blank line in the middle of the code so that you get a single code block. Preview is your friend!

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Unquoted string "i" may clash with future reserved word at test.pl line 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tasks like this, it is useful to form groups of lines in a first step. Then, in a second loop, you have each group in your access, and you can rearrange or modify easily:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# First, form the groups
# Each group starts with a line matching a certain pattern, e.g. /^\-/
my @groups = ();
my $current;
foreach my $line (<DATA>) {  
  chomp $line;
  next unless $line;  
  if ($line =~ /^\-/) {
    push @groups, $current if $current;
    $current = [];
    }
  push @$current, $line;
  }
push @groups,$current if (scalar @$current > 0); # last group

# Now you have the groups, you can manipulate the output 
# and print it comfortably in a modified form 
foreach (@groups) {
  my @current = @{ $_ };
  foreach my $i (0..$#current) {
    if ($i==0) {
      print "$current[$i] $current[$i+2] +SPECIAL\n";
      }
    else {
       print "$current[$i]\n";
      }  
    } 
  }


__DATA__
- VSSC!.extra196 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1055560 1571000 ) N ;
- VSSC!.extra197 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1055560 1571000 ) N ;
- VSSC!.extra198 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1043560 1571000 ) N ;
```

To make it standalone, I have put your sample data as `__DATA__` at the end of the script. You can, of course, read in the lines from a file as well, this would require some slight changes of the first part of the script.

Comment: Your `next unless $line ne ""` is not very good style. It's confusing. Juts say `if $line eq""` or `unless $line`.

Comment: @simbabque Agreed. Double negation is never not bad. :-) I changed it

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than it sounds - your data has a delimiter `;`. 
So you can set `$/` and use that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ";\n";
while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @chunk = split /\n/; 
    print join ( " ", @chunk[0,2], " + SPECIAL" ),"\n";
}


__DATA__
- VSSC!.extra196 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1055560 1571000 ) N ;
- VSSC!.extra197 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1055560 1571000 ) N ;
- VSSC!.extra198 + NET VSSC!
   + DIRECTION INOUT
   + USE GROUND
   + LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
   + PLACED ( 1043560 1571000 ) N ;
```

This prints:

```
- VSSC!.extra196 + NET VSSC!    + USE GROUND  + SPECIAL
- VSSC!.extra197 + NET VSSC!    + USE GROUND  + SPECIAL
- VSSC!.extra198 + NET VSSC!    + USE GROUND  + SPECIAL
```